# ESLint couldn't find the config "prettier/@typescript-eslint" after relocating .eslintrc to parent

Tags: eslint, prettier

I have a folder structure like

```
parentFolder > componentA
             > componentB
             > componentC
```

Each component has a package.json which defines a yarn lint command (eslint "myFilter" --no-error-on-unmatched-pattern). And each component has its own .eslintrc and .prettierrc

When I am in a componentA/B/C folder and run yarn lint, it is working as expected.

Since all of the .eslintrc are the same in each component folder, I moved the file under parentFolder and delete the copies in the component folders. When I call yarn lint, it used the .eslintrc in the parentFolder, but, I am getting an error.

> Oops! Something went wrong! :(
>
> ESLint: 6.8.0.
>
> ESLint couldn't find the config "prettier/@typescript-eslint" to
> extend from. Please check that the name of the config is correct.

I moved the .prettierrc to the parent folder, but, it couldn't find it. What should I do? Thank you

**Update:** I noticed if I add the prettier on the package.json in the parent folder and run the yarn install, it works. But, I don't know if this is the proper way to do it.

Comment: I think the following is a workaround, I had the same issue after upgrade eslint, prettier, and move from a js project to a typescript project.

The first time I remove `prettier/@typescript-eslint` from the `extends` array and all work properly again. After that, I add the `prettier/@typescript-elist` to the `extends` array and it continues working without problems.

This behavior is very strange, I don't know why it fails the first time ‍♂️ and I don't know why it works after a few runs without this key.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

`prettier/@typescript-eslint` has been [removed](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-config-prettier/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#version-800-2021-02-21) in `eslint-config-prettier` v8.0.0. Just remove it from your ESLint config file. The only entry in `extends` that is needed now for Prettier and ESLint to not conflict is `"prettier"` (make sure it's the last one in `extends`).

Comment: To verify. I should also remove `"plugin:prettier/recommended"`, right? My *.eslintrc* file will then contain an array of rules like this: `["plugin:angular/johnpapa", "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended", "prettier"]` (with no plugin prefixed at the line with prittier)?

Comment: No, esling-config-prettier and eslint-plugin-prettier are two different projects. My answer is only about the former. The plugin has its own recommended configuration. Please check its docs.

Comment: I had to remove the same from all extends for it to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

I got the same error when I updated to eslint-config-prettier 8.0.0, I fixed it by changing .eslintrc.js to:

```
    "plugins": ['@typescript-eslint'],
    "extends": ["eslint:recommended", "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"]
```

Make sure your package.json includes:

```
 @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
 @typescript-eslint/parser
```

You can of course include other plugins and other extends, you can find all the optons: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin

Comment: It does not solve many of the problems it have.

Answer (score 8):

`prettier/@typescript-eslint` was removed in `eslint-config-prettier` v8.0.0

see https://github.com/prettier/eslint-config-prettier/issues/173

From v8, there is simpler configuration. Unfortunately there are still many How-Tos on the Internet that mention old config files that are all gone now.

Answer (score 0):

just  to in  the  package .josn  add  this  package
as  dev

```
 "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.30.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.30.0",
   "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
```

in eslint.js look  to  this  file add to try  to  cheack  if  it is the  same

```
module.exports = {
parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
extends: [
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'plugin:react-hooks/recommended',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',  
    'eslint:recommended'
        
],
"plugins": ['@typescript-eslint'],

parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2020,
    sourceType: 'module',
    ecmaFeatures: {
        jsx: true,
    },
},
rules: {
    'react/react-in-jsx-scope': 'off',

},
settings: {
    react: {
        version: 'detect',
    },
},
```

};

Comment: In the extends array you have this line twice: `'plugin:react-hooks/recommended'`

Comment: i  remove  it  thank